# Using HTC Vive Comos with OpenXR

Tags: c++, virtual-reality, htc-vive, openxr

I followed the documentation but I don’t succeed to bind my HTC Vive Cosmos Controller with my application. The compilation return an error with the code below :

```
CHECK_XRCMD(xrSuggestInteractionProfileBindings(m_instance, &suggestedBindings));
```

In fact, it’s not a compiler error but an error window which is displaying.

[image]

I’m using the SDK sources from github and more precisely, the hello_xr sample.
With breakpoints, I can see with CHECK_XRCMD a XR_ERROR_PATH_UNSUPPORTED.
However, I wrote the same path that it is written in the doc :
/interaction_profiles/htc/vive_cosmos_controller

That’s why I don’t understand…

Can u help me, please ?

Thanks for answers !

Answer (score -1):

You must enable the extension `XR_HTC_vive_cosmos_controller_interaction` when you create your XrInstance. This will make the `/interaction_profiles/htc/vive_cosmos_controller` profile available for use.

Comment: Thanks, @mbucchia but I don't know how to enable it. I read the OpenXr specs that says the same thing but it doesn't say how to do. Do you know how I can do this ?

Comment: When you invoke xrCreateInstance(), you pass an XrInstanceCreateInfo struct. The list of extensions is in enabledExtensionNames.

Comment: You said you are using hello_xr, see here: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenXR-SDK-Source/blob/master/src/tests/hello_xr/openxr_program.cpp#L229